# Is it possible to convert 16bit binary number to two characters and save it to text file?

Tags: text-files, ascii, binaryfiles, compression

I want to save some information to a text file(.txt format). To reduce the file size, I use each bit of a 16 bit binary number to represent some information. For example，for a 16 bit binary number`0000 0001 1000 1111`, each bit has its specific meaning. Since any ASCII character is equal to 8 bit binary number, so I want to convert my 16 bit number to two characters and save it:

```
uint16_t a;
a = 13 << 10 | 1 << 3 | 2;// a is a 16bit binary number
char b, c;
b = (char)(a>>8);
c = (char)a;// convert a to two characters
```

Then I will save b and c to a text file. When I read the text file later, I will convert these two characters to 16 bit binary number and get the information. The problem is that I know some ASCII character are not printable, so I wonder to know if there is any problem? Any answer will be much appreciated!

Comment: Non-printable characters are only a problem when you try to print them. Or run the file through some system that can only deal with printable characters. As long as everyone treats the file as the binary data that it is (you should not really call this ASCII -- which by the way has only 7 bits) all is well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will save the characters to a txt file, then I will compress it use a software, winzip for example. I'm not sure if it's possible to do this.

Comment: I think it would prevent a lot of confusion if you called this a binary file and gave it a different extension, say ".bin". Is there some reason you can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem. Whether a file is text or binary or whatever is just a convention. It all depends on how the program interprets the data. A non-unicode aware text editor will display gibberish when you open a UTF-32 encoded text file, even though the data is "text". Similarly with your program. You can name the file with .jpg and as long as your program knows how to handle it it should be alright.

Just be sure to read and write it in binary mode. Some programming languages do small amounts of processing for "text mode", such as replacing a newline with the platform's newline.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Another problem, if I save the character to a .txt file, then I will use a software(for example, winzip) to compress it. When I read the file, I will decompress it first and then convert the character to 16 bit binary number. I think it's possible to do this?

Comment: You just described how to do it so it's definitely possible :). One thing to take into account would be any special handling by winzip of text files. It should be smart enough to not look just at the extension, but if you find any setting to disable it that would be great.